# date passing error in extjs 4.0.2a mvc

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, extjs4, extjs-mvc

my model code is

```
Ext.define('gantt.model.Project', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',   
    fields : [
              { name: 'id', type: 'int', useNull: true, mapping: 'projectid'},
              { name: 'title', type: 'string', mapping: 'projecttitle'},
              { name: 'name', type: 'string', mapping: 'projectname'},
              { name: 'description', type: 'string', mapping: 'projectdesc'},
              { name: 'startdate', type: 'date', mapping: 'startdate', dateFormat :'time'},
              { name: 'enddate', type: 'date', mapping: 'enddate', dateFormat :'time'},
          ]

});
```

my view is

```
Ext.define('gantt.view.projectmgt.projectAdd', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.projectadd',
    title: 'New Project Detail Input Window',
    width: '50%',

    xtype:'fieldset',
    title: 'Project Details',
    collapsible: true,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    layout: 'anchor',
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },
    items :[{
            fieldLabel: 'Title',
            name: 'title',
            xtype: 'textfield'              
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            name: 'name',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'StartDate',
            name: 'startdate',
            xtype: 'datefield',
            format: 'Y/m/d'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'EndDate',
            name: 'enddate',
            xtype: 'datefield',
            format: 'Y/m/d'
        }, {
            xtype: 'htmleditor',
            name: 'description',
            fieldLabel: 'Description',
            height: 200,
            anchor: '100%'
        }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save',
        action: 'show-gantt-view'
    },{
        text: 'Cancel',
        action: 'cancel'
    }]
});
```

my form panel has save button when i click it my Controller execute the following method

```
createProjectGanttpanel: function(btn) {
        var win = this.getProjectAdd().getForm().getValues();
        console.log('PANEL VALUES ARE ::'+win["startdate"]);
        record = Ext.create('gantt.model.Project');
        record.set(win);
        this.getProjectsStore().add(record);
        this.getProjectsStore().sync();
    }
```

this method assigns the values to the model and then store saves them to my database. But I am having problem when I select the date it is in format printed in **Console log as '2012/01/31'** but when i see the **firebug POST tab it show the startdate passed as '-19800000' and enddate passed as '-19800000'**

On the server side when i see to my JAVA Console it shows me the **"startdate":"1970-01-01T05:30:02","enddate":"1970-01-01T05:30:02"** which is incorrect. Due to this the correct date is not viewed in my grid Panel.

What i am doing here wrong in my code. Help me to find the problem so I can solve it soon.

I am using extjs 4.0.2a mvc and JAVA as my server side technology.

Comment: On the server side, the Java Date object uses dates in milliseconds whereas your client uses dates in seconds, no ?

Comment: Can you put a log of what the `record` looks like after you set it?  It could be that this `set` method is not handling it correctly.

Comment: my records look like **1970-01-01 00:00:00** after i set the date. The problem is with the dateformat. After selecting the date i get the date as **2012/01/31** but after assigning it to my model it turns into some junk value like **1970-01-01 00:00:00** whichi is sent to server. Do you have any Idea how to solve this issues ?

Comment: @nico_ekito actually till now Java don't have to do anything here. Just extjs is in use. The format extjs passess the date Java is going to processed that only. So i think the problem is with the extjs dateformat only

Answer (score 0):

Your dateFormat is currently set to `dateFormat: 'time'`, did you tried to change this to:

```
dateFormat: 'Y-m-d h:i:s'
```

This worked for me in a similar setup.

**UPDATE 2012-01-30:**

Check this API doc for more information about formatting dates in ExtJs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date

Answer (score 0):

See if [this](http://biju-allandsundry.blogspot.com/2012/01/ext-js-json-datetime-mapping-in-spring.html) helps you - I had faced a similar issue and decided to consistently use ISO 8601 formatted dates in Ext-JS and Spring, this is the way to get this to work:

http://biju-allandsundry.blogspot.com/2012/01/ext-js-json-datetime-mapping-in-spring.html

To summarize:

Use a custom Jackson ObjectMapper to write dates in ISO8601 format:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature;
 
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper(){
        super.configure(Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    }
}
```

Register this custom object mapper:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven > 
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" >
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="org.bk.simplygtd.web.spring.CustomObjectMapper"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
 </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Use a dateformat of 'c' to handle this in the UI:

```
Ext.define('CUSTOM.model.Proj',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields:[{name:'id', type:'string'},{name:'name', type:'string'}, 
            {name:'startDate', type:'date', dateFormat:'c'}, {name:'completedDate', type:'date', dateFormat:'c'},
            {name:'isDone', type:'boolean'}, {name:'version', type:'string'}]
});
```

Set Ext-JS to submit dates back to server in ISO-8601 format:

```
Ext.JSON.encodeDate = function(o)
{
   return '"' + Ext.Date.format(o, 'c') + '"';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than customising the server side to accept a bogus date format, you could implement a custom `Ext.data.writer.Writer` that simply amends all date fields to be readable by Java. Then when registering the proxy, simply add `writer: 'javajson'` to the config.

```
/**
 * Java compatible Json writer
 * @class My.component.data.writer.JavaJson
 * @extends Ext.data.writer.Json
 */
Ext.define('My.component.data.writer.JavaJson', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.writer.Json',
  alternativeClassName: 'My.component.data.JavaJsonWriter',

  alias: 'writer.javajson',

  //inherit docs
  getRecordData: function(record, operation) {
      var data = this.superclass.getRecordData(record, operation),
          fields = record.fields,
          fieldItems = fields.items,
          nameProperty = this.nameProperty,
          field,
          name,
          value;

      for(f = 0; f < fieldItems.length; f++) {
          field = fieldItems[f];
          if(field.type === Ext.data.Types.DATE) {
              name = field[nameProperty] || field.name;
              value = record.get(field.name);
              data[name] = Ext.isEmpty(value) ? value : value.getTime();
          }
      }

      return data;
  }
});
```